# Passing a return to specify the result of a callback function on the GearmanWorker

Tags: gearman

I am trying to pass some data or an identifier of the result of the operation like 'true' or 'false'. For now I can only think of the return code of the task based on the callback for complete and failed.
Can you give some ideas on how to pass data to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out this one. What I did is that I include a setCompleteCallback on the client and a sendComplete on the the worker. A serialized data sent through sendComplete can be received by the registered callback using setComplete.

```
At worker:
$client->setCompleteCallback('onComplete');
function onComplete($job){
...
}
At client:
$worker->sendComplete('This is the data!');
```